# Prove that any Subspace of Hausdorff is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

[image]

Prove that any Subspace of Hausdorff is Hausdorff

**Attempt**

$\mathcal{T}_Y$={O$\cap$ Y:O$\in\tau$}

Let X be any topology where Y$\subset X$
where (X,$\tau$)

Let a,b $\in Y$.

Since X is Hausdorff then for a$\ne$b,
there exists U,V $\in$ X, s.t a$\in $U and b$\in$V and
U$\cap V=\emptyset$

As a$\in $U we have W= Y$\cap U$ for W$\in\tau$

But for b$\in $ V. we get Y=Y$\cap$V then

( Y$\cap U$ )$\cap$ (Y$\cap V$)=Y$\cap$(U$\cap V)=\emptyset$

Thus ( Y$\cap U$ ) and ( Y$\cap V$ ) are
separate ,thus Hausdorff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Did l miss anything?

Hope l am getting better?

Comment: ..its correct..

Comment: @user2345678 ...its incorrect. There are several errors, as pointed in the answer below.

Comment: when he wrote U= Y$\cap U$, the left side U has a different shape from the right side $U$, so I tought he didn't mean the same set. Reading the proof from this point of view (although not very well written), it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed several \ errors in your attempt although you started in the
correct way. Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a Hausdorff topological space, $Y
\subseteq X$ using the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_Y = \left\{ O \bigcap
Y|O \in \mathcal{T} \right\}$. To prove that $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is
Hausdorff. Take $a, b \in Y$ such that $a \neq b$ then as $\mathcal{T}$ is
Hausdorff there exists $U, V \in \mathcal{T}$ so that $a \in U, b \in V$ and
$U \bigcap V = \emptyset$. Now as $a, b \in Y$ we have that $a \in U \bigcap
Y$ and $b \in V \bigcap Y$. Further $\left( U \bigcap Y \right) \bigcap \left(
V \bigcap Y \right) = \left( U \bigcap V \right) \bigcap Y = \emptyset$,
finally by definition of $\mathcal{T}_Y$ we have that $U \bigcap Y, V \bigcap
Y \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. Thus proving that $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is Hausdorff.

Your assertion that as $a \in U$ we have that $U = Y \bigcap U$ is incorrect
and [it is only true if $U \subseteq Y$] and not needed for the proof,
likewise your assertion that for $b \in V$ we get $Y = Y \bigcap V$ is
incorrect and also does not help with the proof.

Hope this clarify the proof for you

$E$ is a spelling error, it should be $Y$ so that $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the
subspace topology of $Y$. You do not have to construct $U \bigcap Y$ or $V
\bigcap Y$ only show that it is in the subspace topology of $Y$

Comment: Ok. How did you make big tau.. what is E?  I was trying to find how to construct say U$\cap Y$

Comment: @Homer /mathcal{T} gives a calligraphic T as used. You can look at the post in edit mode to see how it’s done.